# Where can I ask how to build a plastic prototype?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I don't know at which Stack Exchange website I can ask the question below, so I'm posting it here.

> I always wondered how companies build the plastic chassis/form-factor for their products. I mean there are some very sophisticated shapes like calculators, monitors, remote-control car toys .. etc all of these products have plastic chassis with colors. How the companies build these?
>
> I mean I know there is 3D printing but as far as I know 3D printing is still at the early stages if I'm not mistaken.

Can you suggest a website for this question?

Comment: While I wouldn't recommending posting on the main site (at least until narrowed down) you might get a few ideas in the Electrical Engineering chat room about enclosure prototypes. 3D printing has been around a long time as has CNC milling that can be used with plastic and end products will normally use injection moulding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a current Stack Exchange site that would take your question.

You'd need a site about manufacturing, but I don't think such a site would work with the SE Q&A model.